# Simulink only runs in auto solver selection but not if solver is selected

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a compllex simulink model which runs only if I choose automatic solver selection. I want to fix the solver across my different experiments so I ned to fix the solver.
[solver selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FRIs.png)

The error I get when choosing a solver is:
Algebraic state in algebraic loop containing <> computed at time 10.39000000000012 is Inf or NaN.  There may be a singularity in the solution.
If the model is correct, try reducing the step size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by tightening the error tolerances) or tweak the initial guess of algebraic loop variable values.

Comment: We're going to need more details about your model, can you reproduce the issue after simplifying parts of the model? Does the solve with automatic solver selection actually exceed 10.4sec or does the automatic step size get extremely small? You might be able to [see which settings the auto selection has chosen](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/use-auto-solver-to-select-a-solver-1.html) and then mimic them

Comment: usually you can solve algebraic loops by putting a memory or a delay block connected to the signal creating the loop. This i the case for example of closed loop control  systems